# Proper use of session_start() with session.cookie_domain

Tags: php

Try as I might, I cannot get my session values on the other side. My set up is:

At the top of page 1:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.domain.com');
session_start();
```

On the sub domain page:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myval']
```

;

What am I doing wrong here? All I get is an empty array.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting `$_SESSION['myval']`, can you show us that?

Answer (score 1):

session_start needs to be called on every page that uses session variables.  not just the first one

Comment: Thanks steelbytes but I am calling session_start on both pages. I forgot to include the function in my post but have since corrected it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: have you tried using session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','.domain.com'); instead of the ini_set?